# How to figure out that 95 pecentile of time calls came back within certain milliseconds

Tags: average

I am working on a project in which I am supposed to do profiling on our `REST Service`. And after that figure it out how much is the `90 percentile` or `95 percentile` of our service. Meaning how much time calls is taking in `90% of time` or `95% percent of time`

Below is the histogram I have created by profiling my service-

```
0 came back between 1 and 2 ms
0 came back between 3 and 4 ms
0 came back between 5 and 8 ms
0 came back between 9 and 16 ms
0 came back between 17 and 32 ms
2205 came back between 33 and 64 ms
141 came back between 65 and 128 ms
50 came back greater than 128 ms
```

From the above histogram it means, `2205` calls came back between `33 and 64 ms`, `141 calls` came back between `65 and 128 ms`.

So now I am trying to figure out how to calculate what is the `90 percentile` or `95 percentile` of this? Means `90 percentage of time` calls came back in how many milliseconds?

I have a map as well for the above histogram, if we cannot figure out this percentile from the above histogram, then we can use this Map as well.

From this Map only, I am creating above histogram-

> {213=1, 114=2, 185=1, 131=1, 40=145, 67=8, 49=35, 537=2, 164=1, 565=1,
>   55=13, 96=1, 546=1, 117=1, 68=10, 62=6, 83=1, 34=333, 41=108, 179=1,
>   48=48, 111=1, 129=1, 69=11, 33=1, 173=1, 61=8, 541=1, 74=7, 180=2,
>   42=78, 47=46, 56=11, 84=2, 70=12, 228=1, 273=1, 46=52, 102=1, 225=1,
>   81=2, 181=1, 563=1, 549=1, 137=1, 73=3, 235=1, 53=17, 90=1, 36=190,
>   118=1, 45=78, 35=267, 72=9, 63=16, 54=11, 271=1, 189=1, 209=1, 175=4,
>   51=23, 203=2, 37=186, 58=5, 196=2, 237=1, 86=3, 44=81, 64=15, 92=3,
>   224=1, 71=8, 251=1, 52=12, 78=3, 43=75, 147=1, 133=1, 580=1, 57=11,
>   263=1, 566=1, 85=1, 243=1, 38=161, 559=1, 80=3, 132=1, 194=1, 107=6,
>   65=5, 183=1, 222=1, 93=1, 60=12, 231=1, 94=1, 66=12, 122=1, 39=135,
>   50=35, 76=1, 59=6, 104=1, 158=1, 113=1, 204=1, 87=1, 115=2}

In the above map, `key` is the number of milliseconds and value is `total number of calls`
So for example -

`213=1`

It means, `1` call came back in `213 milliseconds`.

`114=2`

`2` calls came back in `114 milliseconds`.

Can anyone help me with this? Either I can create the percentile stuff from the `histogram` or the above `Map` as well.

I believe its a simple Mathematics stuff.

Answer (score 1):

The histogram is too coarse grained to give reliable  information about the $95$th percentile. By accident, it is pretty good for the $98$th.

The needed data are almost certainly in the Map, though the order there is not clear.

Find the total number of calls. From the histogram, the number is $2396$.

Let us suppose it is $2400$.

For the $98$th percentile, note that $2\%$ of $2400$ is $48$. Count backwards from the largest waiting time until you get to a time that has $48$ waiting times, counting multiplicities, that are larger than it. The associated time will be the $98$-th percentile.  From the histogram, it looks as if that number is a small amount above $128$ ms.

For the $95$th percentile, note that $5\%$ of $2400$ is $120$. So find the place that has $120$ of the wait times, counting multiplicities, above it. The answer will be somewhere between $65$ ms and $128$ ms, probably quite a bit closer to $65$ than to $128$. But to pin it down precisely, you really do need to use the more detailed information.